# Garbage collecting sockets in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, sockets, garbage-collection

I'm working with a Node library that doesn't explicitly close sockets after it's done with them. Instead it tries to clean up by deleting reference to the socket and letting them be garbage collected.

Googling is failing me: I don't think that is possible for the GC to clean up unclosed sockets. That is, I think that any socket descriptors will still be in use, from the OS's perspective.

Additionally, assuming that I as the library consumer have access to the socket objects, what is the best way for me to close them? I have played around with `end()`, `close()`, and `destroy()` with limited success. Sometimes they seem to block into perpetuity (end/destroy), and other times it seems like the callback is never made (close).

Answer (score 2):

It could be due to the fact that your socket sent a FIN package and hangs up on the connection while waiting for the other end to send the FIN2 message. In cases when the socket on the other side is not nicely closed, your one won't receive any package, thus hanging up forever.
Actually, `end` [sends a FIN packet](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_end_data_encoding) and does not shutdown the socket.

A possible solution could be to [wait for a while on it](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback) by means of `setTimeout` when you invoke the `end` function, then [explicitly destroy it](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_destroy) by means of the function `destroy`. This won't affect your socket if the other end has correctly closed the connection, otherwise it will force the shutdown and all resources should be released.